# Fabric Debug Craslytic Reports : Signup, build Id missing, apply plugin : io.fabric

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, crashlytics, google-fabric

We have programming an Android app and try to implement Crashlytics to our app.

**We have different types of problem .** 
Version we used : 
Android studio version :
3.3

**Gradle version :** 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

**Plugin :**
Fabric for Android studio v4.3.0

**Implementation :** 
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9') { transitive = true }
implementation('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.0@aar') { transitive = true }

**gradle-wrapper.properties :**
 distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.2.1-all.zip

***First Problem :***

When we implement Crashlytics, you know that developers have 3 steps. We can not skip 2,3.steps. Because we have not compiled our application yet. We had two main errors:

**Error 1:**

This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,

**Error 2 :**

```
E/CrashlyticsCore: The Crashlytics build ID is missing.This occurs when 
Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration.
Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
```

So, we had to be disabled "Debug Mod" to complete implementation of Crashlytic.

```
Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder()
        .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build())
        .build();

Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit);  // Tod from Fabric suggested in stackoverflow
```

And implementation was completed.

But we do not want to do that. Because, when we have a crash, it does not  any report to Crashlytics or Firebase. We also want to have debug mod’s crashes.

When we removed -> `....disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)`  -  it shows again : **Error 1, Error 2.**

***Second Problem :***

In gradle ; apply plugin : ‘io.fabric’, we made the comment line, when we remove comments line,  we have errors below :

**Error 3 :**

```
WARNING: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
Affected Modules: app
```

When we searched it, this error related to new android studio gradle. So we needed to make comment line “apply plugin: fabric.io” again.

There is no good solution about that.

To run application we can not remove:

`new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build()` : (due to Error1  Error2)

**So we try to enable report different ways :**

What have we try to add until here?

**1. Enable in gradle :**

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled: true]
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled: false]

    }
```

**2.    Enable in Manifest**

```
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
    android:value="true" />
```

**3.Enable in ADB**

```
  adb shell setprop log.tag.Fabric DEBUG
  adb shell setprop log.tag.CrashlyticsCore DEBUG
```

But still, Crashlytics or Firebase does not get any Debug Crash reports.

We have expecting your solutions.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Does your app have several flavors?

Comment: we solved with adding android.debug.obsoleteApi=true
 to gradle.properties. fabric needs to develop for new gradle. They have bugs. This will allow all old methods and variables. When fabric updated it, do not forget to remove it.

Comment: I managed to fix it without adding what you suggested. I'll explain in a few as an answer.

Comment: Why are you specifying **Proguard** for debug builds?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I managed to get this fixed without adding `android.debug.obsoleteApi=true` in `gradle.properties`.

I basically connected 3 flavors to different `Firebase` projects using proper flavor configuration and the provided `google-services.json` file.

What your gradle file is missing comparing it to mine is this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:$google_services_version" // google-services plugin

    classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:$fabric_tools_version"

}
```

`apply plugin: "io.fabric"`

And finally: `implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1"`

I know `Fabric` is going to shut down this year, but by running the apps this way, they connected to the `Firebase` console with no problem whatsoever.

Regarding the flavor configuration, I downloaded three different `json` files (I have 3 flavors) and added them in the root directory of each flavor. For example:

```
flavor1:
assets
java
res
AndroidManifest
google-services.json (for flavor1)

flavor2:
assets
java
res
AndroidManifest
google-services.json (for flavor2)
```

And that's it. Hope this helps someone.

**EDIT**
So, as you guys may already know, `Fabric` is shutting down and `Firebase Crashlytics` is ready, making this answer deprecated.
Please check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android) so you can successfully update your app and avoid weird behaviors.

Comment: Actually I think fabric solved this error. we remove obsolete=true from our code. Also for different flavors you do not need add separeted google-services.json. You can merge all of them in one google-service.json file

Answer (score 19):

This also happens if you set `ext.enableCrashlytics = false` for a build variant but still try to call `Fabric.with(context, Crashlytics())` in your app initialization code. `ext.enableCrashlytics = false` disables the build plugin (an optimization I made to make my debug builds faster) but then of course the build ID will be missing.

Answer (score 18):

Today I migrated from Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase Crashlytics and encountered a fatal error that didn't keep me going. What I did was this:
In app-> build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
dependencies {
 implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0"
// Add dependency
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
}
```

In general build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

repositories {

    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'  // Crashlytics plugin
}
```

**And of course download the json file from Firebase and insert it in the app folder.**

After completing these simple steps, I received this error when I started the application

> The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics
>   tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review
>   Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid
>   Crashlytics account.

I went to check that there wasn't any code that could call up old Fabric methods, and in fact I discovered that in app-> build.gradle I had this:

```
buildTypes {

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
        **ext.enableCrashlytics = false**
        ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
    }    
}
```

**ext.enableCrashlytics = false** certainly it was a method that referred to the old Fabric, so I removed this line and everything worked perfectly! I hope to help someone with this

Comment: Thank you! Works.

Comment: This line `ext.enableCrashlytics = false` is needed to speed up local debug builds....

Comment: Yes, probably, but in this case it belonged to an old fabric, after the migration it gave problems. Likely they no longer have that method.

Answer (score 11):

just set `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` in ur build.gradle (app)

Answer (score 11):

In my case I was missing Crashlytics plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Put that line at the top of your module's `build.gradle` file e.g.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue when migrating from Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase Crashlytics, following steps fixed the issue for me

- `Clean` your project
- Update `google-services.json` file

Answer (score 3):

Just add this line in your build.gradle (Project):

```
 classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'
```

and this plugin in your build Gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in my app (Android Studio 3.4.1)

I fixed trough conecting to the Fabric Plugin. Creating an account and linking my app to it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i just update `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'` to `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'`
and added `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` to my app level gradle. This solved **Error 2** for me.

Answer (score 1):

if you migrate from **Fabric** to **Firebase** please ensure you've called:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
```

in your *Application* *onCreate()*.

No need any relation to **Fabric** anymore, just follow this guidance:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android

Comment: Explicit initialization of Crashlytics is no longer required

Answer (score 0):

In My case, I hade two modules that used a different version of FireBase Crashlytics.

Answer (score 0):

In My case, I miss this line: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
[image: Apply the Firebase Crashlytics Plugin to your app]

For reference, https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/android-setup

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here and I fixed it by adding Fabric to Gradle

Here's my project Gradle file:

```
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```